# Why JIT if we have NGEN

Tags: .net, clr, jit, ngen

Why do `CLR` need `JIT` compiler to complie `IL` to machine code when it has `NGEN` that does that work at the time of installation.

One more question, how `JIT` will complie `IL` code if it is already NGENed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- because many apps aren't "installed" in that sense, and don't make use of the structures that NGEN require; they are just files on a storage device (or purely in memory, if loaded from an external source)
- because NGEN is tied to hardware, and hardware can *change* during a machine's life
- because the JIT itself can be updated separately to your applications, fixing bugs and improving performance
- because apps use things like plugins and extension points; everything might not be available when you NGEN
- because many apps use meta-programming to emit optimized code for themselves at runtime *based on the exact conditions* (which could be external data not knowable until it is actually invoked at runtime - how ORMs map database columns to objects, for example)
- because in many cases it *isn't worth the overhead* of NGEN - it won't improve things

When NGEN or AOT is a good fit: great, go do that. But it isn't a magic wand that solves every problem.

> One more question, how JIT will complie IL code if it is already NGENed?

Assuming that all the preconditions for the NGEN image being a perfect match are satisfied, then the JIT won't need to be involved.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/why-using-ngen-on-your-assemblies-may-not-be-as-smart-as-you-think/) has some explanations why `NGEN` might be not as attractive as it sounds.

And [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2007/09/15/to-ngen-or-not-to-ngen/) there are very old recommendations from **Microsoft** when to use `NGEN`.

> One more question, how `JIT` will complie IL code if it is already NGENed?

If runtime decides that recompilation is required - it'll ignore NGENed image altogether.